# CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

When I started to train some neural network, it met the `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` but the training could go on without error. Because I wanted to use gpu memory as it really needs, so I set the `gpu_options.allow_growth = True`.The logs are as follows:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:925] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:951] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 7.81GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:972] DMA: 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] 0:   Y
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device:0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 4.00G (4294967296 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
Iter 20, Minibatch Loss= 40491.636719
...
```

And after using `nvidia-smi` command, it gets:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+   
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.27                 Driver Version: 367.27                            
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+   
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |  
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M.
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |   
| 40%   61C    P2    46W / 180W |   8107MiB /  8111MiB |     96%      Default |   
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+   
|   1  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |   
|  0%   40C    P0    40W / 180W |      0MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |   
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+   
                                                                              │
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+   
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |   
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |   
|=============================================================================|   
|    0     22932    C   python                                        8105MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

After I commented the `gpu_options.allow_growth = True`, I trained the net again and everything was normal. There was no the problem of `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY`. Finally, ran the `nvidia-smi` command, it gets:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+   
| NVIDIA-SMI 367.27                 Driver Version: 367.27                            
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+   
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |  
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M.
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |   
| 40%   61C    P2    46W / 180W |   7793MiB /  8111MiB |     99%      Default |   
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+   
|   1  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |   
|  0%   40C    P0    40W / 180W |      0MiB /  8113MiB |      0%      Default |   
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+   
                                                                              │
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+   
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |   
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |   
|=============================================================================|   
|    0     22932    C   python                                        7791MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have two questions about it. Why did the `CUDA_OUT_OF_MEMORY` come out and the procedure went on normally? why did the memory usage become smaller after commenting `allow_growth = True`.

Answer (score 56):

In case it's still relevant for someone, I encountered this issue when trying to run Keras/Tensorflow for the second time, after a first run was aborted. It seems the GPU memory is still allocated, and therefore cannot be allocated again. It was solved by manually ending all python processes that use the GPU, or alternatively, closing the existing terminal and running again in a new terminal window.

Answer (score 24):

By default, tensorflow try to allocate a fraction `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` of the GPU memory to his process to avoid costly memory management.  (See the [GPUOptions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto) comments).
This can fail and raise the `CUDA_OUT_OF_MEMORY` warnings. 
I do not know what is the fallback in this case (either using CPU ops or a `allow_growth=True`).
This can happen if an other process uses the GPU at the moment (If you launch two process running `tensorflow` for instance).
The default behavior takes ~95% of the memory (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34514932/2642845)).

When you use `allow_growth = True`, the GPU memory is not preallocated and will be able to grow as you need it. This will lead to smaller memory usage (as the default option is to use the whole memory) but decreases the perfomances if not use properly as it requires a more complex handeling of the memory (which is not the most efficient part of CPU/GPU interactions).

Comment: I only launch one process. After I commented the `allow_growth = True`, tensorflow should use the whole memory because of the default option but actually it only used 7793M memory which was even not larger than 8107M when I used `allow_growth = True`(that was where I was confused). That training could go on show that the net actually doesn't need so much memory.

Comment: By default, tensorflow consider only 95% of the gpu memory as the whole memory so 7793MB seems right (see extra link). The use of more memory in `allow_growth` should be related to the size of your network (I did not find any source about that yet...). For instance if you allocate two 4GB variables on the GPU, it will fit with `allow_growth` (~8GB) but not on the preallocated memory, hence raising the `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` warnings

Comment: After setting `allow_growth=True` and `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.5` , still I faced this error in Windows10 GPU RTX 2080 machine.  And this issue resolved by resizing the image by half.

Answer (score 18):

I faced this issue when trying to train model back to back. I figured that the GPU memory wasn't available due to previous training run. So I found the easiest way would be to manually flush the GPU memory before every next training.

Use nvidia-smi to check the GPU memory usage:

```
nvidia-smi

nvidia-smi --gpu-reset
```

The above command may not work if other processes are actively using the GPU.

Alternatively you can use the following command to list all the processes that are using GPU:

```
sudo fuser -v /dev/nvidia*
```

And the output should look like this:

```
USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/dev/nvidia0:        root       2216 F...m Xorg
                     sid        6114 F...m krunner
                     sid        6116 F...m plasmashell
                     sid        7227 F...m akonadi_archive
                     sid        7239 F...m akonadi_mailfil
                     sid        7249 F...m akonadi_sendlat
                     sid       18120 F...m chrome
                     sid       18163 F...m chrome
                     sid       24154 F...m code
/dev/nvidiactl:      root       2216 F...m Xorg
                     sid        6114 F...m krunner
                     sid        6116 F...m plasmashell
                     sid        7227 F...m akonadi_archive
                     sid        7239 F...m akonadi_mailfil
                     sid        7249 F...m akonadi_sendlat
                     sid       18120 F...m chrome
                     sid       18163 F...m chrome
                     sid       24154 F...m code
/dev/nvidia-modeset: root       2216 F.... Xorg
                     sid        6114 F.... krunner
                     sid        6116 F.... plasmashell
                     sid        7227 F.... akonadi_archive
                     sid        7239 F.... akonadi_mailfil
                     sid        7249 F.... akonadi_sendlat
                     sid       18120 F.... chrome
                     sid       18163 F.... chrome
                     sid       24154 F.... code
```

From here, I got the PID for the process which was holding the GPU memory, which in my case is 24154.

Use the following command to kill the process by its PID:

```
sudo kill -9 MY_PID
```

Replace MY_PID with the relevant PID.

Answer (score 5):

**Tensorflow 2.0 alpha**

The problem is, that Tensorflow is greedy in allocating all available VRAM. That causes issues for some people.

For Tensorflow 2.0 alpha / nightly use this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.gpu.set_per_process_memory_fraction(0.4)
```

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/using_gpu

Comment: my code doesnt seem to identify the gpu object in config, i think the actual implementation is something like tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)

Answer (score 0):

I was experienced memory error in Ubuntu 18.10.
When i changed resolution of my monitor from 4k to fullhd (1920-1080) memory available become 438mb and neural network training started.
I was really surprised by this behavior.

By the way, i have Nvidia 1080 with 8gb memory, still dont know why only 400mb available

Comment: You can use nvtop or nvidia-smi to see what processes are using the VRAM

Comment: TF preallocates memory, and that is not a bad thing in itself. So that the GPU memory is full does not indicate the TF has no memory left. What you need to know is how much of TFs internal memory is still available.

Answer (score 0):

Environment:
1.CUDA 10.0
2.cuNDD 10.0
3.tensorflow 1.14.0
4.pip install opencv-contrib-python
5.git clone https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow
6.Allowing GPU memory growth

[image]

[Reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth)

Answer (score 0):

```
fuser -k /dev/nvidia[0]
```

Worked for me.

Thanks to https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/11-gb-of-gpu-ram-used-and-no-process-listed-by-nvidia-smi/44459/16

Answer (score 0):

Check the **correctness of the input dataset**.
İf you have a null input list may occur this error too.
The situation that I faced in **Colab** with **tf.keras**