# CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: How to activate multiple GPUs from Keras in Tensorflow

Tags: memory, deep-learning, keras

I am running a large model on tensorflow using Keras and toward the end of the training the jupyter notebook kernel stops and in the command line I have the following error:

```
 2017-08-07 12:18:57.819952: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:955] failed to alloc 34359738368 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
```

This I guess is simple enough - I am running out of memory. I have 4 NVIDIA 1080ti GPUs. I know that TF uses only one unless specified. Therefore, I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a good working example of how to utilise all GPUs in Keras
2. In Keras, it seems it is possible to change gpu_options.allow_growth=True, but I cannot see exactly how to do this (I understand this is being a help-vampire, but I am completely new to DL on GPUs)

see [CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465503/cuda-error-out-of-memory-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See this [Official Keras Blog](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html)
2. Try this:

   ```
   import keras.backend as K

   config = K.tf.ConfigProto()
   config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
   session = K.tf.Session(config=config)
   ```