# CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY on Tensorflow#object_detection/train.py

Tags: python, object-detection, tensorflow

I'm running Tensorflow Object Detection API to train my own detector using the `object_detection/train.py` script, found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection). The problem is that I'm getting `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` constantly.

I found some suggestions to reduce the batch size so the trainer consumes less memory, but I reduced from 16 to 4 and I'm still getting the same error. The difference is that when using batch_size=16, the error was thrown in step ~18 and now it is been thrown in step ~70. **EDIT:** *setting batch_size=1 didn't solve the problem, as I still got the error at step ~2700.*

What can I do to make it run smoothly until I stop the training proccess? I don't really need to get a fast training.

**EDIT:**
I'm currently using a GTX 750 Ti 2GB for this. The GPU is not being used for anything else than training and providing monitor image. Currently, I'm using only 80 images for training and 20 images for evaluation.

Comment: add some more information regarding your GPU size, training data size and are you using GPU simultaneously anywhere else?

Comment: @SmitShilu Added the requested information. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: I am sorry, I am not able to reproduce in mine but It might be the image size issue if each image is high resolution or refer to this link https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1854

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution for my problem. The `batch_size` was not the problem, but a higher `batch_size` made the training memory consumption increase faster, because I was using the `config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True` configuration. This setting allows Tensorflow to increase memory consumption when needed and tries to use until 100% of GPU memory.

The problem was that I was running the `eval.py` script at the same time (as recommended in their tutorial) and it was using parte of the GPU memory. When the `train.py` script tried to use all 100%, the error was thrown.

I solved it by settings the maximum use percentage to 70% for the training proccess. It also solved the problem of stuttering while training. This may not be the optimum value for my GPU, but it is configurable using `config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.7` setting, for example.

Comment: Hello @Minoru, do you put config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.7 in trainer.py after
session_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,
                                    log_device_placement=False)
?
Thank you.

Comment: @willSapgreen I didn't notice anything about the `session_config` variable. Just used `config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.7` right after the `config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True` line.

Comment: You can also do this in code: `import tensorflow as tf;tf.config.gpu.set_per_process_memory_fraction(0.7)`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory) for more options.

Answer (score 1):

I think is not about batch_size, because you can start the training at first place.

open a terminal ans run

> nvidia-smi -l

to check if there are other process kick in when this error happens. if you set batch_size=16, you can find out pretty quick.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to dedicate the GPU for training and use the **CPU for evaluation**.

- **Disadvantage:** Evaluation will consume  large portion of your CPU, but only for a few seconds every time a training checkpoint is created, which is not often.
- **Advantage:** 100% of your GPU is used for training all the time

To target CPU, set this environment variable before you run the evaluation script:

```
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1
```

You can explicitly set the evaluate batch job size to 1 in `pipeline.config` to  consume less memory:

```
eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1;
}
```

If you're still having issues, TensorFlow may not be releasing GPU memory between training runs. Try restarting your terminal or IDE and try again. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57989591/5752730) has more details.