# Limit GPU memory allocation in skflow

Tags: tensorflow, skflow

I am training convnets with Tensorflow and skflow, on an EC2 instance I share with other people. For all of us to be able to work at the same time, I'd like to limit the fraction of available GPU memory which is allocated.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory?rq=1) does it with Tensorflow, but since I'm using sklfow I'm never using a `tf.Session()`.

Is it possible to do the same thing through skflow ?

Comment: I have added the option. See my edit in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this moment, you can only control the number of cores (`num_cores`) to be used in estimators by passing this parameter to estimator.

One can add `gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)` to `tf.ConfigProto` as suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory?rq=1) you linked to achieve what you need.

Feel free to submit a PR to make changes [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow/blob/master/skflow/estimators/base.py#L160) as well as adding this additional parameters to all estimators. Otherwise, I'll make the changes some time this week.

Edit:

I have made the changes to allow those options. Please check "Building A Model Using Different GPU Configurations" example in examples folder. Let me know if there's any particular need or other options you want to add. Pull requests are always welcomed!