# Tensorflow uses same amount of gpu memory regardless of batch size

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and I am trying to train on the CIFAR 10 dataset.  I noticed that no matter what batch size I use according to my nvidia control panel I am using 97% of my gpu memory.  I tried batch sizes of 100 down to 2 and in each case my gpu memory usage is always 97%.  Why would it do this?

```
def batchGenerator(batch_size = 32):
    bi = 0
    random.shuffle(train_data)
    while bi + batch_size < len(train_data):
        x = np.zeros((batch_size, 32, 32, 3))
        y = np.zeros((batch_size, 10))
        for b in range(batch_size):
            x[b] = train_data[bi + b][0]
            if random.choice((True, False)):
                img = cv2.flip(x[b], 0)
            if random.choice((True, False)):
                img = cv2.flip(x[b], 1)
            y[b][train_data[bi + b][1]] = 1
        bi += batch_size
        yield(x, y)

with tf.Session() as s:
    s.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    for epoch in range(100):
        a = 0.0
        i = 0
        for x_train, y_train in batchGenerator(2):
            outs = s.run([opt, accuracy], feed_dict = {x: x_train, y_exp: y_train, p_keep: 0.5})
            a += outs[-1]
            i += 1
        print('Epoch', epoch, 'Accuracy', a / i)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is related to [How to prevent tensorflow from allocating the totality of a GPU memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory)

---

TensorFlow uses by default **all the memory** of your GPU, and this is the **normal behavior**. From the tutorial [Using GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/using_gpu/index.html#allowing-gpu-memory-growth):

> By default, TensorFlow maps nearly all of the GPU memory of all GPUs visible to the process. This is done to more efficiently use the relatively precious GPU memory resources on the devices by reducing memory fragmentation.

---

They also provide different options if you need to reduce the memory taken by TensorFlow, such as:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4
session = tf.Session(config=config, ...)
```

(from the linked docs), to limit the memory use to 40% of the GPU's available memory.

Comment: Dead link. Could you update for Tensorflow 2?