# How does one have TensorFlow not run the script unless the GPU was loaded successfully?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia, cudnn

I have been trying to run some TensorFlow training on some machine with GPUs however, whenever I try to do so I get some type of error that seems to say it wasn't able to use the GPU for some reason (usually memory issue, or cuda issue or cudnn etc). However, since the thing TensorFlow does automatically is to just run in CPU if it can't use the GPU its been hard to tell for me if it was actually able to leverage the GPU or not. Thus, I wanted to have my script just fail/halt unless the GPU is being used. How do I do that?

---

For the sake of an example, currently I have the message:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla P100-SXM2-16GB
major: 6 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.4805
pciBusID 0000:85:00.0
Total memory: 15.93GiB
Free memory: 15.63GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:85:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla P100-SXM2-16GB
major: 6 minor: 0 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.4805
pciBusID 0000:85:00.0
Total memory: 15.93GiB
Free memory: 522.25MiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:85:00.0)
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:385] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:352] could not destroy cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:532] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms)
```

where it seems to load all the cuda fine but then at the end complains. The complaining lines are:

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:385] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:352] could not destroy cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:532] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms)
```

we could try to debug these specific bug but for the moment it proceeds to train however, I have no idea if its using cpu or gpu. Can we just have it not proceed training if any weird cuda/cudnn or whatever gpu bug comes up?

Comment: Maybe try `log_device_placement=True` as explained on: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu

Comment: Check how force_gpu [does it](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2c8d0dca978a246f54c506aae4587dbce5d3bcf0/tensorflow/python/framework/test_util.py) . There [maybe](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7026#issuecomment-281741007) a bug in the logic, so just use it for inspiration

Answer (score 1):

Use `with tf.device('/gpu:0'):`. This will kill your program if `/gpu:0` doesnt exist.

eg see https://github.com/hughperkins/tensorflow-cl/blob/tensorflow-cl/tensorflow/stream_executor/cl/test/test_binary_ops.py#L52

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=False)) as sess:
        with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
            tf_a = tf.placeholder(tf_dtype, [None, None], 'a')
            tf_b = tf.placeholder(tf_dtype, [None, None], 'b')
            tf_c = tf.__dict__[tf_func](tf_a, tf_b, name="c")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list all available devices in tensorflow: [How to get current available GPUs in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow). If GPU is not in the list, you can make the program throw exceptions.