# Iterate cpu and gpu devices in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am aware that Tensorflow can explicitly place computation on any devices by `"/cpu0"` or `"/gpu0"`. However, this is hard-coded. Is there any way to iterate all visible devices with built-in API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current available GPUs in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you would like to have:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

def get_all_devices():
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    return [x.name for x in local_device_protos]

all_devices = get_all_devices()
for device_name in all_devices:
    with tf.device(device_name):
        if "cpu" in device_name:
            # Do something
            pass
        if "gpu" in device_name:
            # Do something else
            pass
```

Code is inspired from the best answer here: [How to get current available GPUs in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow)