# How to list visible Tensorflow devices without allocation?

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow

One can list the currently visible devices to Tensorflow with:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
LOCAL_DEVICES = device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

(see: [How to get current available GPUs in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow))

However, this seems to initialize and allocate these GPUs. How can we list the devices without allocating them?

Comment: Can you get to the OS and call something like `lspci` ?

Comment: What gives you the indication that the listed GPUs have been allocated after call to device_lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GPU devices, the TensorFlow `list_local_devices()` function is a wrapper around the `cuDeviceGetCount()`, `cuDeviceGet()`, and `cuDeviceGetProperties()` functions in the [CUDA API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__DEVICE.html). (In addition, there is typically one "CPU device" that uses all of the cores in the local system.)

The simplest solution might be to call these CUDA APIs directly. This [script](https://gist.github.com/f0k/63a664160d016a491b2cbea15913d549) shows how to do this from Python using `ctypes`.