# does tensorflow-gpu library automatically run tensorflow code (non GPU) on GPU?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Do I have to customize code written for the non GPU Tensorflow library to suit tensorflow-gpu library?

I have a gpu and would like to run the python code written for only non GPU tensorflow library. Can I simply install the tensor-flow gpu module and run the code? Or is there any code changes that I will have to make in order to run the code on GPU?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have installed `tensorflow-gpu` and everything runs fine, by default, it should run on your GPU except if:

- You specifically state in your code that the graph should run on CPU with something like `with tf.device('/cpu:0')`,
- You hide your GPU from tensorflow with `os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = ''`.

You can check that tensorflow finds your GPU using ([credit to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45182952/6246880))

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

Also, if you have an NVIDIA gpu, you can check the usage of your GPU using `nvidia-smi` and see that tensorflow is indeed using your GPU.

Now, if you'd like to allocate a specific GPU and/or limit the memory that a graph can allocate on the GPU memory, you might want to have a look [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu) for more details.