# How use TPU in google colab

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu

Google colab brings TPUs in the Runtime Accelerator. I found an example, How to use TPU in [Official Tensorflow github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/models/experimental/keras/mnist.py). But the example not worked on google-colaboratory. It stuck on following line:

```
tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(model, strategy=strategy)
```

When I [print available devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow) on colab it return `[]` for TPU accelerator. Does anyone knows how to use TPU on colab?

[image]

Comment: I tried training a model with keras using the TPU runtime but it was really slow. What the GPU runtime trained in 2 minutes, the TPU runtime trained in 58 minutes. I'm waiting for a fix too.

Comment: To use the TPU, uou'll need to connect to it explicitly using the recipe in the answer below. (The use of TPUs isn't automatic like GPUs, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a Colab-specific TPU example:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/tpu/blob/master/tools/colab/shakespeare_with_tpu_and_keras.ipynb

The key lines are those to connect to the TPU itself:

```
# This address identifies the TPU we'll use when configuring TensorFlow.
TPU_WORKER = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']

...

tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
training_model,
strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
    tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)))
```

(Unlike a GPU, use of the TPU requires an explicit connection to the TPU worker. So, you'll need to tweak your training and inference definition in order to observe a speedup.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I add **TPU_WORKER** line and resolved the running error. but I didnt gain any significant improvement. It's too slow.

Comment: My recommendation is to ask a separate question that includes a link to your notebook. Often, existing models require some adjustment in order to speed things up, and it's easy to end up in a case where critical operations are performed on the CPU rather than TPU.

Comment: Thanks, It was a bug in my code and nothing to do with TPU.

Comment: This example only shows how to do it on keras. Are there any possible methods for "pure" tensorflow or pytorch?

Comment: I noticed even the network speed is faster with GPU environment compared to CPU and TPU. I noticed downloading dataset from Kaggle.

Comment: I am getting error as AttributeError: 'Activation' object has no attribute 'outbound_nodes' when i try to use TPU on google colab.

Comment: Hi folks, please ask distinct questions for distinct issues. This question is about the basics of connecting to the TPU rather than performance optimization or error debugging.