# Python: how to get the number of GPUs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I'm using Keras with Tensorflow to replicate a DQN. Actually I'm using 2 GPUs, but I want to make my code executable in every machine, regardless the number of GPUs it has. So my question is: how can I get the number of GPUs present in my PC? I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow) but it gets me a lot of info I don't need. Is there any other way to get the number of GPUs?

Comment: The answer you linked literally has the answer, they enumerate the GPUs, you just have to get the length of that list.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wanted to know if there are another method. With that, you had the number of gpus + cpus present in your system

Comment: No, they specifically filter to only get the GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many GPUs are there running `tf.contrib.eager.num_gpus()` will give you the answer.

Comment: When I try to use that, it gives me the following error:
  File "<string>", line 28
    def single_image_random_dot_stereograms(depth_values, hidden_surface_removal=True, convergence_dots_size=8, dots_per_inch=72, eye_separation=2,5, mu=0,333299994, normalize=True, normalize_max=-100, normalize_min=100, border_level=0, number_colors=256, output_image_shape=[1024, 768, 1], output_data_window=[1022, 757], name=None):
                                                                                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax