# pixel-cnn (tensorflow-gpu) not recognising GPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, device-driver

I'm trying to run the pixel-cnn neural network available on [github](https://github.com/openai/pixel-cnn). Following the instructions in README.md I run the following code in cmd:

```
train.py -i ./data_dir/ -o ./save_dir -g 1
```

I'm using one gpu and created the two folders ./data_dir and ./save_dir within the same directory as train.py for loading & saving the data. When doing so I get the following error message:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation model_1/ones: node model_1/ones (defined at \OneDrive - MNG\Matura Arbeit\Projects\pixel-cnn-master\pixel_cnn_pp\model.py:36) was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device. The requested device appears to be a GPU, but CUDA is not enabled.
```

It seems that the tensorflow doesn't recognise the GPU but when checking the devices available to tensorflow (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow)) both my CPU and GPU show up as "/device:CPU:0" and /device:GPU:0". Also, when running other programs with tensorflow-gpu it work perfectly fine.

I have installed *tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0*. As for the CUDA I'm pretty sure I have installed version 10.0, as shown by `nvcc --version`. Although when running `nvidia-smi` it shows that *CUDA version 10.1* is installed.

(edited:)I am using an Anaconda evironment (Windows 10) with *tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0*. The GPU I'm using is a *GTX 1050Ti* with Max-Q Design and *driver version 436.30*. As for CUDA I'm pretty sure I have installed *version 10.0*, as shown by `nvcc --version`. Although when running `nvidia-smi` it shows that *CUDA version 10.1* is installed.

Comment: Just checking your CUDA compute level of your card please? And are you able to run any tensorflow commands with the gpu version?

Comment: @JCooke I'm using a GTX 1050Ti (with Max-Q Design). Cheking [this list](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) I now see that it isn't listed as compatible, which seems weird to me. Is this really the case, that the 1050Ti can't compute with CUDA?
(Edit:) And yes, any other program I run works perfectly with tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: No I think it's just missing from the list. Should be supported.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment/conda? What version of CUDA are you pointing to in PATH? Please can you also update your question with a bit more info on your dev environment as this error can be caused by CUDA linking problems, although strange it is only happening on this file.

Comment: @JCooke yes I'm using an anaconda environment (I updated the question accordingly). PATH is set to point to ...\CUDA\v10.0\bin and CUDA_PATH to ...\CUDA\v10.0.
Furthermore, to check if tf-gpu was really working with other files, I quickly ran [this script](https://gist.github.com/j-min/baae1aa56e861cab9831b3722755ae6d#file-test_single_gpu-py), which executed perfectly fine with the GPU carrying all the load (checked it with task manager)