# Tensorflow 2: how to switch execution from GPU to CPU and back?

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

In `tensorflow` 1.X with standalone `keras` 2.X, I used to switch between training on GPU, and running inference on CPU (much faster for some reason for my RNN models) with the following snippet:

```
keras.backend.clear_session()

def set_session(gpus: int = 0):
    num_cores = cpu_count()

    config = tf.ConfigProto(
        intra_op_parallelism_threads=num_cores,
        inter_op_parallelism_threads=num_cores,
        allow_soft_placement=True,
        device_count={"CPU": 1, "GPU": gpus},
    )

    session = tf.Session(config=config)
    k.set_session(session)
```

This `ConfigProto` functionality is no longer available in `tensorflow` 2.0 (there I'm using the integrated `tensorflow.keras`). In the beginning, it is possible to run `tf.config.experimental.set_visible_devices()` in order to e.g. disable the GPU, but any subsequent calls to `set_visible_devices` result in `RuntimeError: Visible devices cannot be modified after being initialized`. Is there a way of re-initializing the visible devices or is there another way of switching the devices available?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [`tf.device`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device) to explicitly set which device you want to use. For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf    

model = tf.keras.Model(...)

# Run training on GPU
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    model.fit(...)

# Run inference on CPU
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    model.predict(...)
```

If you only have one CPU and one GPU, the names used above should work. Otherwise, [`device_lib.list_local_devices()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d42facc3cc9611f0c9722c81551a7404a0bd3f6b/tensorflow/python/client/device_lib.py#L27) can give you a list of your devices. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow) gives a nice function for listing just the names, which I adapt here to also show CPUs:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

def get_available_devices():
    local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
    return [x.name for x in local_device_protos if x.device_type == 'GPU' or x.device_type == 'CPU']
```

Comment: Do you know by default the tensorflow is running on GPU or CPU?

Comment: is there a way to set that for the whole scope of the script? I mean, without the with statement? Something like `tf.set_device('/cpu:0')`?

Comment: This could be a practical solution, but note that as soon as you enter `tf.device('/cpu:0'):`, TF will still allocate GPU memories. I think this is a limitation of TF.

Comment: Assuming you want to run on CPU only, you can get around TensorFlow's habit of allocating GPU memory by setting the environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to the empty string before initializing TensorFlow.

Comment: @LucasAzevedo if you want to set the device for the whole scope you can use: ```physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'); tf.config.set_visible_devices(physical_devices[0], 'GPU')```. This is implemented since tensorflow version 2.1.

Answer (score 2):

Does using [`tf.device`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device) can help you?

With that, you can set some operations either on CPU or on GPU.

Answer (score 0):

I would just restart the kernel, this worked for me