# You have requested more vCPU capacity than your current vCPU limit of 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, unreal-engine4

I am trying to host Unreal Engine Pixel Streaming Build to AWS and while doing the setup I am getting stuck at the launch of Instance. I followed this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=auWKfiLQW4w).

Please look at the error below:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated since I am a beginner in AWS.

Comment: Are you using Free tire of AWS?

Comment: @SmartCoder No. And I have been assigned as IAM user.

Answer (score 30):

There are default limits for various Amazon EC2 instance types. These are based upon the total number of vCPUs simultaneously running. You can access this information by selecting **Limits** in the sidebar of the EC2 management console.

[image: EC2 instance limits]

You can click the **Request limit increase** button to submit a request for the limit to be increased.

These limits are sometimes to **prevent fraud** (eg people consuming lots of resources and then not paying their bill), and sometimes to **protect people from accidentally running the more-expensive instances** (eg the X family).

The `g4dn.4xlarge` shown in that video tutorial costs `$1.204/hour` (depending upon region used).

Comment: Please give `limits` link on Amazon. I cant  find it

Comment: Ah! It looks like they have moved it. See: [Amazon EC2 service quotas - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html)

Comment: In pricing does not have remotly that price . Nombre de la instancia
Tarifa por hora bajo demanda
vCPU
Memoria
Almacenamiento
Rendimiento de la red
g4dn.xlarge 0,526 USD 4 16 GiB 125 GB NVMe SSD Hasta 25 gigabits

Comment: Wait, so you have to type on a text box explaining why you want to use a paid service to wait for a human to allow it? That's crazy! Worst case they should require pre-buying some kind of credit if there's no other way to prevent fraud.

Comment: Be prepared to waste your time waiting and negotiating. I had 0 vCPU limit. When I applied to increase it so I can run a minimal GPU instance, I got a quite meaningless response: "I am sorry but at this time we are unable to approve your service quota increase request. Service quotas are put in place to help you gradually ramp up activity and decrease the likelihood of large bills due to sudden, unexpected spikes.". I personally do not see other way to "gradually ramp" up, than going from zero vCPU to non-zero vCPU count. So be warned and maybe consider other service providers as a solution.

Comment: For what it's worth I asked for 100 vCPUs (from 0) and they gave me 8 after around 90 minutes. I only really needed 4 so it worked out.

Answer (score 9):

Check out this aws doc:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-on-demand-instance-vcpu-increase/ It will let you see your current limit, and if you need to request an increase (or just choose a different instance type/class)

Also double-check you are in the right region. An increase is only for the region you request it in. You can check what your limit is via the Quotas page: https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home?region=us-east-1#!/dashboard

Comment: Thanks. I can see my limit which is 0 but I cant request limit increase so I already contacted my administrator.

Comment: The limits page was deactivated for me, to view your service quotas or to request an increase, I had to use the AWS Service Quotas console

Answer (score 1):

Go to this page: https://eu-north-1.console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home/services/ec2/quotas

1. Find the instance type you want to increase your limit for
2. Request for the limit

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the previous answers and in case others find it useful, in my case I needed to increase the quotas for both 'spot' and 'on-demand' instance types.

**To increase the quota for 'spot' instances**, simply visit this AWS link to check your current quota and request a quota increase:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home/services/ec2/quotas/L-34B43A08

**To increase the quota for 'on-demand' instances**, visit the following link instead:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home/services/ec2/quotas/L-1216C47A

The button `Request Increase at Account-level` on the top-right of each page will lead you to a simple form in which you can specify the new limit. That is it! After a few minutes, I got some e-mail from AWS confirming the quota increase and it works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

You need to contact AWS support and get it fixed. How to do that is given in the following video.

**How to activate a blocked AWS account & increase vCPU limits**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkmaxX3VBP8

AWS does this for security reason and prevent any fraud. It's kind of a safety feature to prevent you accidently overspending.