# "You have requested more vCPU capacity", when launching G instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have this error when launching `g4dn.xlarge` instance

```
You have requested more vCPU capacity than your current vCPU limit of 0 allows for the instance bucket that the specified instance type belongs to. Please visit http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ec2-request to request an adjustment to this limit.
```

However my `Service Quota` is like this below

[image]

`All G and VT Spot Instance Requestss` is 8

And I don't launch another `G` instance at the same time.

Where should I check?

Or is it relevant?(EC2 -> Limit, It shows  Limits page deactivated)

(I can jump to the service quota page from the link in this page though)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you are requesting a spot instance when you configure the launch of your vm. There is a check box under the Advanced section of the launch wizard.

Comment: Ii works, thank you very much!! but I didn't check spot instance check box before when launch another instance. Why it is necessary?

Comment: And spot instance has the risk to terminated? So If I want to use not spot instance, What quota should I increase?

Comment: AH I found the request form for on-demand instance. maybe my problem is solved, I was confused spot with on-demand

Comment: I literally had the same problem this past week and went through the same stages of confusion. The quota request default violates the principal of least surprise!

Comment: In case it is useful, in my case I needed to increase the quotas for both 'spot' and 'on-demand' instance types. I posted an answer here with details on how to solve it easily: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78146759/2430526