# GPU availability check

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, gpu

I am trying to test that my Jupyter notebook is using the GPU or not but when I check with this code, It shows me '0' GPU's available. But, My system is i7 10th Generation and GEFORCE RTX 2060. I have downloaded cuda and NVIDIA CNN added to the system variables and in anaconda downlaoded
tensorflow GPU but I don't know why its not recognizing my GPU.

```
'''
    print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
'''
>>>>Num GPUs Available:  0
```

Answer (score 0):

try use [gputil](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/anderskm-gputil-python-gpu-utilities):

```
import GPUtil
GPUtil.showUtilization()
```

try also look here - [How to get current available GPUs in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow)

Comment: It did not work. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: what is the error? @hemanthvema

Comment: I want to make my Jupyter notebook always use my GPU instead of using CPU, but I tried so many times every time it is saying, GPU is 0 . I don't know whether it is possible to use my Jupyter notebook every time with my GPU or not.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, 0 is the first available GPU. If you had none, `GPUtil.getAvailable()` would return `[]`instead of  `[0]`.