# Detecting actively used GPUs in TensorFlow's MirroredStrategy (not available)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In TensorFlow, detecting the number of **available** GPUs is a trivial task that can be resolved [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow).

However, when in the context of a [MirroredStrategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy), unless the user provides the information of how many GPUs are being used, it is not possible to my knowledge to actually get the number of active GPUs.

This leads to some uncanny behaviours, for instance, when defining a [custom keras metric](https://github.com/LucaCappelletti94/extra_keras_metrics/blob/master/extra_keras_metrics/binary_metric.py) such as [F1 Score](https://github.com/LucaCappelletti94/extra_keras_metrics/blob/master/extra_keras_metrics/f1score.py) by extending the abstract class [Keras Metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Metric): when training for instance with 4 GPUs, the metric scores are **aggregated by sum**, leading to metrics that are no longer defined from 0 to 1, but from 0 to 4.

This does not happen when using the default Keras Metrics, and I am at this time investigating their source code trying to understand how they avoid this: I expect for instance they have a method to get how many GPUs are being used and simply divide by this number.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, while I have not resolved how to obtain the count of **used** GPUs, I have resolved how to avoid the need for it altogether in my use case, which boils down to being an aggregation of weights.

To aggregate properly the weights, one can specify in the [`add_weight`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#add_weight) method one of the [`AggregationMethod`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/AggregationMethod).

In my use case, also, since I needed sum aggregation of the various components of a confusion metric, such as True Positives etc..., to let TensorFlow handle some of the more complex use cases, I ended up using the [`Sum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Sum) metric class for composition, specifically one for each part of the confusion matrix.