# Find GPU Name using python

Tags: python

I am wandering how I can find name of the model of my PC'S gpu (ex. RTX 3090). Not the manufacturer but just the name of the model.

Comment: For what OS?  This is not information that can be grabbed through just standard Python.  For example, if you're using linux, you may be able to just run the `lspci` command or similar and parse the output.

Comment: I am thinking about Windows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38580201/15250079 mentioned here for tensorflow.