TensorFlow install: Warning: Could not find TensorRT / Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries
I am trying to install TensorFlow on Ubuntu/VSCode  and I get these error message and can't the problem.
Here are the error message:
(.venv) user:~/Desktop/Code$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
2024-05-10 15:36:48.869402: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-05-10 15:36:48.891469: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-05-10 15:36:49.200446: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-05-10 15:36:49.396177: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-05-10 15:36:49.414822: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...

Out put of:
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

user:~/Desktop/Code$ /bin/python3 /home/user/Desktop/Code/init.py
2024-05-11 13:30:27.259737: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-05-11 13:30:27.668506: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-05-11 13:30:28.176893: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-05-11 13:30:28.528011: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-05-11 13:30:28.758580: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
Num GPUs Available:  0


Could you please guide me on how to fix these issue?
Thank you
I did install Nvidia 550 Driver, CUDA 12.4, CuDnn and TensorRt without issue (Test passed for CuDnn - ./mnistCUDNN)
Then I installed :
pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]

Here is my set-up:
(.venv) user:~/Desktop/Code$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               user
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: MS-7D96 2.0 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 6.5.0-28-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 38 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1992 (dpkg), 9 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: bash 5.1.16 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: Unity 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Adwaita 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Yaru-dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: vscode 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: Intel i7-14700K (28) @ 5.500GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel Device a780 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         GPU: NVIDIA 01:00.0 NVIDIA Corporation Device 2783 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           Memory: 3384MiB / 31854MiB 
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
                                                                   
                                                                   

(.venv) user:~/Desktop/Code$ nvidia-smi
Fri May 10 15:27:57 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.67                 Driver Version: 550.67         CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 ...    Off |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   46C    P8              9W /  220W |     390MiB /  12282MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2232      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            173MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2406      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                           38MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5068      G   ...,262144 --variations-seed-version=1        104MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5702      G   ...erProcess --variations-seed-version         62MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


Here are some output:
(.venv) user:~/Desktop/Code$ python3 --version
Python 3.10.12
(.venv) user:~/Desktop/Code$ python -m pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.16.1
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /home/user/Desktop/Code/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: absl-py, astunparse, flatbuffers, gast, google-pasta, grpcio, h5py, keras, libclang, ml-dtypes, numpy, opt-einsum, packaging, protobuf, requests, setuptools, six, tensorboard, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, termcolor, typing-extensions, wrapt
Required-by: 
(.venv) user:~/Desktop/Code$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2024 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Mar_28_02:18:24_PDT_2024
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.4, V12.4.131
Build cuda_12.4.r12.4/compiler.34097967_0


As described here there is a bug in tensorflow 2.16.1. You can either downgrade to 2.15.1 or use the script env_vars.sh that is explained on that page. I created a script with this name and called it using source ./env_vars.sh. Now tensorflow can find my GPU.
Here is what has resolved the problem for me. There are two solutions, one with tensorflow 2.15.1 without any modifications and another one with tensorflow 2.16.1 using env_vars.sh.
For both versions we need a python script tfgputest.py with the following contents:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
print('looking for GPUs')
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    print("Name:", gpu.name, "  Type:", gpu.device_type)

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/38580201/7609868
print('looking for GPUs again')
local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
for x in local_device_protos:
    if x.device_type == 'GPU':
        print(x.physical_device_desc)

tensorflow 2.15.1
Create a virtual environment (you can install the venv package using sudo apt install python3-venv), switch to it, install tensorflow 2.15.1 and call the script:
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ venv/bin/pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]==2.15.1
$ python3 tfgputest.py
2024-05-14 15:08:05.142872: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-05-14 15:08:05.142897: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-05-14 15:08:05.143554: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
looking for GPUs
Name: /physical_device:GPU:0   Type: GPU
looking for GPUs again
device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6

tensorflow 2.16.1
Here we need the env_vars.sh:
#!/bin/bash

NVIDIA_DIR=$(dirname $(dirname $(python -c "import nvidia.cudnn;print(nvidia.cudnn.__file__)")))
for dir in $NVIDIA_DIR/*; do
    if [ -d "$dir/lib" ]; then
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$dir/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
    fi
done

Now install tensorflow 2.16.1, source env_vars.sh and call the python script:
$ venv/bin/pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]==2.16.1
$ source env_vars.sh
$ python3 tfgputest.py
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
looking for GPUs
Name: /physical_device:GPU:0   Type: GPU
looking for GPUs again
device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6

One difference here is that for the 2.16.1 version all the warnings are gone that are shown for 2.15.1.
Problem with nvida_uvm
An additional option to solve the problem is mentioned here. I have this problem on one of my laptops (Lenovo T480 with an Nvidia MX 150 running Debian 12). Here I have to reload the nvidia_uvm module using
$ sudo modprobe -r nvidia_uvm
$ sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm


Since downgrading didn't work for me, I would like try the env_vars.sh but not sure how to proceed.

Here is the output:
(venv) user:~/Code$ source env_vars.sh
(venv) user:~/Code$ /home/user/Code/venv/bin/python /home/user/Code/tfgputest.py
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
looking for GPUs
Name: /physical_device:GPU:0   Type: GPU
looking for GPUs again
device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 SUPER, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.9
(venv) user:~/Code$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
2024-05-16 16:33:07.382816: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2024-05-16 16:33:07.404841: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-05-16 16:33:07.720071: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-05-16 16:33:08.020974: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-05-16 16:33:08.034411: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2024-05-16 16:33:08.034552: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:998] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

And still get the Could not find TensorRT error

Also, it seems that if I turn off/on the compute and get back into VSCode and run tfgputest.py again I get this output again and have to do source env_vars.sh again
(venv) user:~/Code$ python3 tfgputest.py [] looking for GPUs looking for GPUs again

The difference between the two calls is that the call of venv/bin/python uses the packages that are installed in the virtual environment and the call of just python3 does not (it uses the packages of the system wide installation). Therefore you have this virtual environment.

If we have
W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
WE should install pip install nvidia-tensorrt
And all we be right
