# how to implement tensorflow session configuration

Tags: python, memory, tensorflow, config

I want to set the gpu limitation as instructed in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory).

But my code goes like this:

```
deep_grap = tf.Graph()
with deep_grap.as_default():
    ### graph definition here
    ### graph definition here

with tf.Session(graph=deep_grap) as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    ### more computations here
```

In this case, how do I set the configuration in my code?
I don't have a direct `sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))`line here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the session configuration, a `tf.ConfigProto` in the `tf.Session()` initializer in the `with` statement:

```
deep_graph = tf.Graph()
with deep_graph.as_default():
    ### graph definition here
    ### graph definition here

config = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=...)

with tf.Session(graph=deep_graph, config=config) as sess:
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
    ### more computations here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deep_grap = tf.Graph()
with deep_grap.as_default():
    ### graph definition here
    ### graph definition here
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)
cfg = tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options)
with tf.Session(graph=deep_grap, config=cfg) as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    ### more computations here
```