# How to release tensors from memory when not in need anymore?

Tags: tensorflow

I have hypothetical graph which has a series of computations as follows:

```
a_0 = tf.placeholder()
a_1 = some_op_1(a_0)
a_2 = some_op_2(a_1)
a_3 = some_op_3(a_2)
```

Observe that when computing `a_3`; `a_0` and `a_1` are not needed and hence they can be discarded prior to allocating memory for `a_3`. Is there some way to ask TensorFlow to perform this memory optimization (agree that there is some cost in time)?

Please note that this is not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory) question about allocating memory only when needed.

EDIT: This network will not be trained, so don't worry about backprop.

Comment: It's done automatically -- by the time `a_3` computation starts, TensorFlow will have already discarded `a_0` and `a_1`. You can use https://github.com/yaroslavvb/memory_util to see timeline of memory allocations/deallocations to verify this is indeed the case

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Your `memory_util` tool doesn't show anything with the gpu, only the cpu. If memory is being deallocated, your tool doesn't show it. I haven't seen your tool work.

Comment: @A.Hendry which system? There may be an issue with how TF reports memory on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TensorFlow uses reference counting to release the memory used by a tensor as soon as it is no longer used. The values of `a_0` and `a_1` will be deleted as soon as there are no more references to them, and in the latest builds of TensorFlow (post-1.0 nightly builds) some operations will even reuse the input buffer for the output if they have the same shape and element type.

Comment: I'm guessing that's due to [203a4d98](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/203a4d98) ? ReLU for forward-only networks is the most relevant one, it would be good if reuse happened there

Comment: Yes, it applies to all unary and binary elementwise ops (including ReLU), and a few others.

Comment: I am sorry. I asked this questions because I am getting OOM errors when I am feeding double the expected image size for a convolution only network. I assumed it was due to the above reason. I'll double check my memory calculations withe @YaroslavBulatov 's script.

Comment: @priyatham - If you don't have control flow, you can also try running `linearize.linearize()` from https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/tree/master/linearize before first `session.run` -- that script forces deterministic memory efficient execution order, as opposed to TensorFlow's random order (which uses magnitudes more memory in some special cases)

Comment: Is this really true ? Last time I checked to release a tensor you need to destroy the entire session, which is not very convenient in some cases