# Blas SGEMM launch failed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just installed  TensorFlow-GPU 1.0.1 on Win10 GTX GEFORCE 850M with CUDA 8.0 and Cudnn v5.1.
when I try to figure out if the installation was successful, I run the

> mnist_with_summaries.py

in

> C:\Users...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\examples\tutorials\mnist

When I run the code in Jupyter Notebook, it prints

> Accuracy at step 0: 0.068
>
> Accuracy at step 10: 0.6795
>
> Accuracy at step 10: 0.6795
>
> Accuracy at step 20: 0.8062
>
> Accuracy at step 30: 0.8455
>
> Accuracy at step 40: 0.8737
>
> Accuracy at step 50: 0.8735
>
> Accuracy at step 60: 0.8851
>
> Accuracy at step 70: 0.8815
>
> Accuracy at step 80: 0.8863
>
> Accuracy at step 90: 0.8918

And the kernel just died after print above message.

When I try to run the code in command prompt, it returns error:

> failed to create cublas handle
>
> attempting to perform BLAS operation using StreamExecutor without BLAS support
>
> Internal error: Blass SGEMM launch failed: a.shape=(10000,784),b.shape=(784,500)

And this Internal error message appears three times.( too many error message, I just write down something I think useful. If anyone need more information, tell me).

I then try to run:

```
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
print(sess.run(c))
```

And the output is:
[[ 22. 28.]
[ 49. 64.]]
This time the code runs without error.
But it should output:
Device mapping:

> /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 850M
>
> id: 0000:05:00.0
>
> b: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
>
> a: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
>
> MatMul: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0

[[ 22.  28.]
[ 49.  64.]]

I am totally lost. Could someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

How much memory do you have on your graphics card? You may be running out of memory. There are ways to force TensorFlow to limit memory usage-- see: [How to prevent tensorflow from allocating the totality of a GPU memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory/34200194)

But I wonder if TF doesnt handle low memory situations gracefully.