# What does a tensorflow session exactly do?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, gpu

I have tensorflow's gpu version installed, as soon as I create a session, it shows me this log:

> I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0
>   with properties:  name: GeForce GTX TITAN Black major: 3 minor: 5
>   memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.98 pciBusID 0000:01:00.0 Total memory: 5.94GiB
>   Free memory: 5.31GiB I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0  I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y  I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:975] Creating
>   TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN
>   Black, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)

And when I check my GPU memory usage, around 90% of it gets consumed.

Tensorflow documentation does not say anything about this. Does it take control of the gpu ? Why does it consume most of the memory ?

Comment: I don't know exactly what tf.Session() does, but about memory allocation of the GPU, give a look at answers and link in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278021/memory-estimation-for-convolution-neural-network-in-tensorflow/44278911#44278911

Comment: @PietroTortella Thanks for that. I have a question for you, I arrived at this post by trying to execute tensorflow, PyTorch, caffe in a single script. When I tried to make a Session as a global variable in the same script it gave me an error `current context was not created by the StreamExecutor` but I don't see it when I create this Session inside a function. Do you know what is going wrong ? This is why i would like to know what is Session doing exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TensorFlow sessions allocate ~all GPU memory on startup, so they can bypass the cuda allocator.

Do not run more than one cuda-using library in the same process or weird things (like this stream executor error) will happen.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is this like a tensorflow specific issue ? Because I have been running other machine learning libraries within the same script and I do not see any problems there.

Comment: You might not see errors but it's likely something weird will happen with the cuda context.