# TF KMeansClustering doesn't run on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, k-means

Running on Ubuntu 16.04, latest (1.1.0) tensorflow (installed via `pip3 install tensorflow-gpu`), CUDA8 + CUDNN5.

The code looks more or less like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.learn import KMeansClustering

trainencflt = #pandas frame with ~30k rows and ~300 columns
def train_input_fn():
    return (tf.constant(trainencflt, shape = [trainencflt.shape[0], trainencflt.shape[1]]), None)

configuration = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(log_device_placement=True)
model = KMeansClustering(num_clusters=k,
                         initial_clusters=KMeansClustering.RANDOM_INIT,
                         relative_tolerance=1e-8,
                         config=configuration)
model.fit(input_fn = train_input_fn, steps = 100)
```

When it runs I see:

```
2017-06-15 10:24:41.564890: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:887] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7335
pciBusID 0000:81:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 7.81GiB
2017-06-15 10:24:41.564934: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0
2017-06-15 10:24:41.564942: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y
2017-06-15 10:24:41.564956: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci bus id: 0000:81:00.0)
```

Memory gets allocated:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    1       548    C   python                                        7745MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But then none of the operations are performed on the GPU (it stays at 0% all the time, the CPU utilization does skyrocket on all cores):

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.66                 Driver Version: 375.66                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   1  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:02:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 29%   43C    P8    13W / 180W |   7747MiB /  8114MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Not seeing any placement logs (even though I specified `log_device_placement` to be True).

I did try [the simple GPU examples](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu) and they were working just fine (at least the placement logs were looking fine).

Am I missing something?

Comment: TensorFlow by default allocates all available memory.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory

It may not be running on GPU because this does not have GPU kernels written for it.

Comment: @jkschin yes I'm aware of the memory allocation patterns - was just showing that as proof of using TF GPU. As for gpu kernels, I tried going through the code and the internals seem to be using a lot of basic TF operations, which I think should work on the GPU, but I'm not sure.

Comment: An experiment you can try would be to assert tf.device and no soft placement, and then see what errors are thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went through the codebase - TF 1.1.0 simply didn't have a GPU kernel.