# Tensorflow: How do you monitor GPU performance during model training in real-time?

Tags: performance, tensorflow, gpu

I am new to Ubuntu and GPUs and have recently been using a new PC with Ubuntu 16.04 and 4 NVIDIA 1080ti GPUs in our lab. The machine also has an i7 16 core processor.

I have some basic questions:

1. Tensorflow is installed for GPU. I presume then, that it automatically prioritises GPU usage? If so, does it use all 4 together or does it use 1 and then recruit another if needed?
2. Can I monitor in real-time, the GPU use/activity during training of a model?

I fully understand this is basic hardware stuff but clear definitive answers to these specific questions would be great.

EDIT:

Based on this output - it this really saying that nearly all the memory on each one of my GPUs is being used?

[image]

Comment: For 2: Try ```nvidia-smi``` in a separate terminal window.

Comment: `watch -n0.1 nvidia-smi` for every 0.1 second usage

Comment: Many thanks - see edit

Comment: Also in my experience tensorflow my default grabs all memory on all GPUs. To avoid this, I set the option `gpu_options.allow_growth` of the session configuration to `True`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233 .

Comment: `nvidia-smi -l` also does the trick

Comment: this is best solution @jakub-bartczuk

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Tensorflow automatically doesn't utilize all GPUs, it will use only one GPU, specifically first gpu `/gpu:0`

   You have to write multi gpus code to utilize all gpus available. [cifar mutli-gpu example](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py)
2. to check usage every 0.1 seconds

   `watch -n0.1 nvidia-smi`

Comment: `nvidia-smi` already has the option to refresh using the `-l` or `-lms` flag, so `watch -n0.1 nvidia-smi` is equavilent to `nvidia-smi -lms 100`
Just for the readers, not saying it's better.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest **nvtop**, it shows real-time status and easier to watch than nvidia-smi. It also shows in a graph.

```
$ sudo apt install nvtop
$ nvtop
```

[image]

Comment: I like this one, very useful.

Answer (score 6):

Try this command:

```
nvidia-smi --query-gpu=utilization.gpu --format=csv --loop=1
```

Here is a demo:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. If no other indication is given, a GPU-enabled TensorFlow installation will default to use the first available GPU (as long as you have the Nvidia driver and CUDA 8.0 installed and the GPU has the necessary [compute capability](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus), which, [according to the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux) is 3.0). If you want to use more GPUs, you need to use [`tf.device`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device) directives in your graph (more about it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu)).
2. The easiest way to check the GPU usage is the console tool [`nvidia-smi`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/alt-nvidia-current-smi.1.html). However, unlike `top` or other similar programs, it only shows the current usage and finishes. As suggested in the comments, you can use something like `watch -n1 nvidia-smi` to re-run the program continuously (in this case every second).

Answer (score 1):

All the above commands use `watch`, it's much more efficient to keep the context alive by using the builin looper:
`nvidia-smi -l 1`.

If you want to see something like `htop` and `nvidia-smi` at the same time, you can try [glances](https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/) (`pip install glances`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GCP, please take a look at this script which allows you to monitor GPU utilization in StackDriver, you can also use it to collect nvidia-smi data using `nvidia-smi -l 5` command and reporting those statistics for you to track.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ml-on-gcp/tree/master/dlvm/gcp-gpu-utilization-metrics

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use `nvidia-smi`. Just keep in mind that depending on your workload you might not see any change in the load if the task completes between 2 sampling events.

Also keep in mind that the maximum sampling interval is 1/6 second as per: http://manpages.org/nvidia-smi

> Utilization rates report how busy each GPU is over time, and can be used to determine how much an application is using the GPUs in the system.
>   Note: During driver initialization when ECC is enabled one can see high GPU and Memory Utilization readings. This is caused by ECC Memory Scrubbing mechanism that is performed during driver initialization.
>
> GPU
>   Percent of time over the past sample period during which one or more kernels was executing on the GPU. The sample period may be between 1 second and 1/6 second depending on the product.
>
> Memory
>   Percent of time over the past sample period during which global (device) memory was being read or written. The sample period may be between 1 second and 1/6 second depending on the product.