# Does using Numpy operations in Tensorflow 2.0 impact its performance?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am studying the transformer code [here](https://github.com/thisisiron/transformer-tf2/blob/master/model.py) as an example.

The positional encoding function below uses numpy for all of its operations. Then it casts them back to TF tensor when returning the result. Does such a pattern impact the performance when running the code especially when I run it on an GPU? Is that recommended to use only TF operations when implementing a model?

```
def get_positional_encoding(self, max_len):
    """PE_(pos, 2i) = sin(pos/10000^(2i/d_model))
    PE_(pos, 2i+1) = cos(pos/10000^(2i/d_model))
    """

    pos = np.expand_dims(np.arange(0, max_len), axis=1)
    div_term = np.array([[1 / np.power(10000, (2 * (i//2) / self.d_model)) for i in range(self.d_model)]])       

    pos = pos * div_term

    pe = np.zeros((max_len, self.d_model))
    pe[:, 0:self.d_model//2] = np.sin(pos[:, 0::2])
    pe[:, self.d_model//2:] = np.cos(pos[:, 0::2])

    pe = np.expand_dims(pe, 0)

    print(pe.shape)

    return tf.cast(pe, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: I think tensor board will help you in this,check if the GPU performance in both the cases,check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544603/tensorflow-how-do-you-monitor-gpu-performance-during-model-training-in-real-tim)

Comment: you cannot use numpy in your model implementation, because tensorflow cannot differentiate through numpy operations.  in other words, having numpy operations in a tensorflow model would break the gradient flow and the model would not be train-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it does impact the performance generally this is assuming that you can properly execute the code without any errors.

One factor is the **time required passing/copying the values from CPU to GPU**, which adds a lot of **overhead time**, the larger the matrices.

**Tensorflow** is built to run in the **GPU**, so when you are using all Tensorflow operations in every part of your code, you will see a **drastic improvement in performance** just because of the time required in **passing values from CPU to GPU**, this is not considering the optimizations applied when using Tensors for computations.