# Why is the gpu usage bouncing from 0 to 99% (Volatile GPU-Util, nvidia-smi) in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow

I am using two graphic cards and the GeForce gtx980 with 4GB, where I compute my neuronal network is always jumping from 0 to 99% and from 99% to 0% (repeating) at the last line of the pasted shell output.

After around 90seconds it did the first calculation. I put my images one after another into the neuronal network (for-loop). And the following calculations only need 20 seconds (3 epochs) and the GPU jumps between 96 and 100%.

Why is it jumping at the beginning?

I use the flag:

```
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
```

Can I be sure that is really using not less megabytes than `nvidia-smi -lms 50` is showing me?

```
2017-08-10 16:33:24.836084: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-10 16:33:24.836100: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-10 16:33:25.052501: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-08-10 16:33:25.052861: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 980
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.2155
pciBusID 0000:03:00.0
Total memory: 3.94GiB
Free memory: 3.87GiB
2017-08-10 16:33:25.187760: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:523] A non-primary context 0x8532640 exists before initializing the StreamExecutor. We haven't verified StreamExecutor works with that.
2017-08-10 16:33:25.188006: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-08-10 16:33:25.188291: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: GeForce GT 730
major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.9015
pciBusID 0000:02:00.0
Total memory: 1.95GiB
Free memory: 1.45GiB
2017-08-10 16:33:25.188312: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 0 and 1
2017-08-10 16:33:25.188319: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:832] Peer access not supported between device ordinals 1 and 0
2017-08-10 16:33:25.188329: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:961] DMA: 0 1 
2017-08-10 16:33:25.188335: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   Y N 
2017-08-10 16:33:25.188339: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 1:   N Y 
2017-08-10 16:33:25.188348: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 980, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
Epoche: 0001 cost=  0.620101001  time=  115.366318226
Epoche: 0004 cost=  0.335480299  time=  19.4528050423
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent tensorflow from allocating the totality of a GPU memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory)

Comment: No, the question is not, why it is totally allocated. It is more about why cpu usage jumps (jumping from 0 to 99% and from 99% to 0% (repeating)) at the moment and then it stops to jump