# How to run two tensorflow session on the same GPU in parallel?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is it possible to run two sessions on the same GPU concurrently? I am very new to Tensorflow and don't know how to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it unsafe to run multiple tensorflow processes on the same GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145100/is-it-unsafe-to-run-multiple-tensorflow-processes-on-the-same-gpu)