# Tensorflow serving : Using a fraction of GPU memory for each model

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have one GPU at my disposal for deployment but multiple models need to be deployed. I don't want to allocate the full GPU memory to the first deployed model because then I can't deploy my subsequent models. While training, this could be controlled using `gpu_memory_fraction` parameter.
I am using the following command to deploy my model -

`tensorflow_model_server --port=9000 --model_name=<name of model> --model_base_path=<path where exported models are stored &> <log file path>`

Is there a flag that I can set to control the gpu memory allocation?

Thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory?rq=1) help?

Comment: @Imran No, my query is regarding memory allocation inside tensorflow serving.

Comment: You can find an open bug here https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/249. Tldr; there doesn't seem to be an option and apparantly you will have to change the option manually and recompile the binary as explained in the post I linked.

Answer (score 3):

The new TF Serving allowed to set flag `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction`  in this [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/pull/694/)

Answer (score 1):

I have just add one flag to config gpu memory fraction.
https://github.com/zhouyoulie/serving