# Tensorflow: Setting allow_growth to true does still allocate memory of all my GPUs

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, nvidia

I have several GPUs but I only want to use one GPU for my training. I am using following options:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True)
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
```

Despite setting / using all these options, all of my GPUs allocate memory and

`#processes = #GPUs`

How can I prevent this from happening?

**Note**

1. I do not want use set the devices manually and I do not want to set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` since I want tensorflow to automatically find the best (an idle) GPU available
2. When I try to start another `run` it uses the same GPU that is already used by another tensorflow process even though there are several other free GPUs (apart from the memory allocation on them)
3. I am running tensorflow in a docker container: `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-gpu-py`

Comment: It seems very weird. could you please try to post the full code and the TF version you're using?

Comment: did you try to specify initial memory fraction? `gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory

Comment: The full code is more than 5 scripts, so I cannot show you the full code, unfortunately, but I think I made my point clear? Or is there anything specific you would like to see? I have added the tensorflow version I am working on. @MatanHugi

Comment: No, I have not, but I am sure this will not help me with my problem. @yauheni_selivonchyk

Comment: Tensorflow has no logic to find the beast (idle) GPU available.

Comment: Hm, okay that's bad but okay, at least it shouldn't allocate memory on every single GPU neither should it start as many processes as there are GPUs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer you a method `mask_busy_gpus` defined here: https://github.com/yselivonchyk/TensorFlow_DCIGN/blob/master/utils.py

Simplified version of the function:

```
import subprocess as sp
import os

def mask_unused_gpus(leave_unmasked=1):
  ACCEPTABLE_AVAILABLE_MEMORY = 1024
  COMMAND = "nvidia-smi --query-gpu=memory.free --format=csv"

  try:
    _output_to_list = lambda x: x.decode('ascii').split('\n')[:-1]
    memory_free_info = _output_to_list(sp.check_output(COMMAND.split()))[1:]
    memory_free_values = [int(x.split()[0]) for i, x in enumerate(memory_free_info)]
    available_gpus = [i for i, x in enumerate(memory_free_values) if x > ACCEPTABLE_AVAILABLE_MEMORY]

    if len(available_gpus) < leave_unmasked: ValueError('Found only %d usable GPUs in the system' % len(available_gpus))
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ','.join(map(str, available_gpus[:leave_unmasked]))
  except Exception as e:
    print('"nvidia-smi" is probably not installed. GPUs are not masked', e)
```

Usage:

```
mask_unused_gpus()
with tf.Session()...
```

Prerequesities: *nvidia-smi*

With this script I was solving next problem: on a multy-GPU cluster use only single (or arbitrary) number of GPUs allowing them to be automatically allocated.

Shortcoming of the script: if you are starting multiple scripts at once random assignment might cause same GPU assignment, because script depends on memory allocation and memory allocation takes some seconds to kick in.

Answer (score 20):

I had this problem my self. Setting `config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True`
 Did not do the trick, and all of the GPU memory was still consumed by Tensorflow. 
The way around it is the undocumented environment variable `TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH` (I found it in 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3e21fe5faedab3a8258d344c8ad1cec2612a8aa8/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc#L25)

Setting `TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH=true` works perfectly.

In the Python code, you can set

```
os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = 'true'
```

Comment: Great! But note that if you are using SLURM, you will need to add "export TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH=true" to your sbatch script, because you won't be able to set environment variables from within python!