# How can I use a part of my graphic cores?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

Simply in tensorflow we can run our project on CPU or GPU. I have a GTX-1080 with 2500 cores. when we use a GPU in tensorflow all of the cores and memory of the graphic card is involved.

How can I use a part or certain number of my graphic cores in tensorflow ?

Comment: Not possible at the moment - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but is it generally impossible? I mean, Can I limit the number of cores in another way except Tensorflow? for example with CUDA ?

Comment: core graphics tag is not suitable for this question