# Why is GeForce GTX 1080 Ti slower than Quadro K1200 on training a RNN model?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

**Problem type**: regression

**Inputs**: sequence length varies from 14 to 39, each sequence point is a 4-element vector.

**Output**: a scalar

**Neural Network**: 3-layer Bi-LSTM (hidden vector size: 200) followed by 2 Fully Connected layers

**Batch Size**: 30

**Number of samples per epoch**: ~7,000

**TensorFlow version**: tf-nightly-gpu 1.6.0-dev20180112

**CUDA version**: 9.0

**CuDNN version**: 7

Details of **the two GPUs**:

GPU 0:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
totalMemory: 11.00GiB freeMemory: 10.72GiB
[image]

[device_placement_log_0.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19K5kRMUdFLd51yfaFv7BwPzprn0V2rZm)

nvidia-smi during the run (using 1080 Ti only):

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 385.69                 Driver Version: 385.69                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108... WDDM  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 20%   37C    P2    58W / 250W |  10750MiB / 11264MiB |     10%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Quadro K1200       WDDM  | 00000000:03:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 39%   35C    P8     1W /  31W |    751MiB /  4096MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

GPU 1:
name: Quadro K1200 major: 5 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.0325
totalMemory: 4.00GiB freeMemory: 3.44GiB
[image]

[device_placement_log_1.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K0V-GaoGh_yJD6yFLb3SXWZBm0L_J7K6)

nvidia-smi during the run (using K1200 only):

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 385.69                 Driver Version: 385.69                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108... WDDM  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 20%   29C    P8     8W / 250W |    136MiB / 11264MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Quadro K1200       WDDM  | 00000000:03:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 39%   42C    P0     6W /  31W |   3689MiB /  4096MiB |     23%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

**Time spent for 1 epoch**:

GPU 0 only (set environment var "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"=0): ~60 minutes

GPU 1 only (set environment var "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"=1): ~45 minutes

Set env. var. to "**TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT**=4" during both tests.

**Why is the better GPU (GeForce GTX 1080 Ti) slower on training my neural network?**

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update**

Another set of tests on MNIST dataset using a [CNN model](https://github.com/martin-gorner/tensorflow-mnist-tutorial/blob/master/mnist_4.2_batchnorm_convolutional.py) showed the same pattern:

Time spent for training 17 epochs:

GPU 0 (1080 Ti): ~59 minutes

GPU 1 (K1200): ~45 minutes

Comment: Is either of the GPUs being used for graphics as well?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos, Yes, the Quadro K1200 was used for graphics (two mornitors, resolutions: 1920x1200 and 1280x1024). The GeForce GTX 1080 Ti was not used for graphics or activities other than training the model.

Comment: One out of two options: (1) TF is deciding which GPU is 0 and which is 1 different from nvidia (look in the tf startup logs to see what it decides) or (2) this particular model is faster on the CPU than on the GPU (tf by default won't run on quadro k1200 because there is not enough compute capacity on it). Can you log device placement to see?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos, Thanks for the options. The text under my question "details of the two GPUs" (i.e. "name : GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1... ") was copied from tf screen logs, which tells us the env. var. setting of "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES" is working (pointing to the desired single GPU for each test). I just checked that quadro k1200 has a Compute Capability of 5.0, which is larger than the required value (3.0) to run GPU version of Tensorflow. Besides, I didn't show in the question, I saw the temperature change of the target GPU (increasing from 30 to 60 degree C) during the two tests

Comment: Can you [log the op device placement](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu#logging_device_placement) to confirm that when you're using the slower GPU the GPU is actually being used?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos, thanks for the tutorial for logging device placement. I have uploaded the two log files in the question part under the two pictures. Most of the nodes/ops are placed on GPU with only a few exceptions.

Comment: Forgot to mention, in order to do these two tests, I have to set env. var. to "TF_MIN_GPU_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT=4" during both tests.

Comment: One suggestion, post your code as well.  Maybe some operation you are doing is very slow.  On a side note, it sounds like you're doing regression on DNA/RNA.  For your input, your model is definitely over-specified.  3 layer/200 node LSTM is way too much, I'd suggest starting with a single layer with 64 nodes and optimizing from there.

Comment: @thc, My full code is too long (over 1,000 lines) to post here. I have posted the comparison results for training MNIST with a CNN model (https://github.com/martin-gorner/tensorflow-mnist-tutorial/blob/master/mnist_4.2_batchnorm_convolutional.py). I've added it under the "Update " at the bottom of the question. The finding is similar: the 1080 Ti still spent more time on training.

Comment: Can you show us what happens if you run nvidia-smi during the computation with both GPUs?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos, I have added the nvidia-smi results during both runs (after creating the input buffer but only trained for less than 100 steps) in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The memory usage seems off (why is it using more memory from the 1080 if it's not serving graphics). I think stackoverflow is the wrong forum for this; can you file a github issue with a shorter script we can run which reproduces the problem in your machine? Thanks

Comment: @AlexandrePassos, I think TensorFlow by default tries to use all possible GPU memories no matter how much they actually need (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory). I have tested the two GPUs with a CNN code on training MNIST, which showed the same pattern. Please find the link of the CNN code in the **Update** part of my question (at the bottom). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The official [tensorflow document](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/using_gpu) has the section "Allowing GPU memory growth" introducing two session options to control GPU memory allocation. I tried them separately to train my RNN model (using only GeForce GTX 1080 Ti):

- `config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True` and
- `config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.05`

Both of them shortened the training time from the original ~60 minutes per epoch to ~42 minutes per epoch. I still don't understand why this helps. If you can explain it, I will accept that as the answer. Thanks.