# numba and tensorflow together gives CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, numba

I have used numba and tensorflow in python to calculate a 3-d loop problem.

Firstly I used numba several times to prepare the input data, and everything was fine.
Then I used tensorflow to de deep learning, and everything was fine.

Next, when I went back to do the above procedure for the second time, i.e. to use numba, it gave me an error CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY.

If I killed the thread and restarted the kernel, I could run it but still failed at the second run.

It seems that the problem is in tensorflow, but I don't know.
I have added numba.cuda.defer_cleanup() at the beginning and ending of the code but it didn't help much.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: tensorflow by default reserves all GPU memory for its own use.  You can modify this behavior, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory)

Answer (score 1):

You might try adjusting the fraction of visible memory that TF tries to take in its initial allocation.
For example: Assume that you have 12GB of GPU memory and want to allocate ~4GB:

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.333)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

or

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True 
sess = tf.Session(config=config,graph=detection_graph)
```

In the second method, you will tell the TF to allow the GPU growth. These options should help you to get out of your issue