# Cannot start Tensorboard when tensorflow is running

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I cannot start a tensorboard instance when tensorflow is already running and using the GPU. The error is below. Apparently Tensorflow blocks all GPU memory on start independent of what it actually requires. Is there a way to start tensorboard while a tensorflow process is running or does it always have be started first?

```
totalMemory: 5,93GiB freeMemory: 41,56MiB
2018-06-02 15:28:11.053634: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1435] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-06-02 15:28:11.321850: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:154] Internal: CUDA runtime implicit initialization on GPU:0 failed. Status: out of memory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/bin/tensorboard", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_main())
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 36, in run_main
    tf.app.run(main)
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 45, in main
    default.get_assets_zip_provider())
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/program.py", line 166, in main
    tb = create_tb_app(plugins, assets_zip_provider)
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/program.py", line 201, in create_tb_app
    flags=FLAGS)
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 126, in standard_tensorboard_wsgi
    plugin_instances = [constructor(context) for constructor in plugins]
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/backend/application.py", line 126, in <listcomp>
    plugin_instances = [constructor(context) for constructor in plugins]
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/beholder/beholder_plugin.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.most_recent_frame = im_util.get_image_relative_to_script('no-data.png')
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/beholder/im_util.py", line 254, in get_image_relative_to_script
    return read_image(filename)
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/beholder/im_util.py", line 242, in read_image
    return np.array(decode_png(image_file.read()))
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/beholder/im_util.py", line 159, in __call__
    self._lazily_initialize()
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/plugins/beholder/im_util.py", line 137, in _lazily_initialize
    self._session = tf.Session(graph=graph, config=config)
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1560, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/home/pascalwhoop/Documents/Code/University/powerTAC/python-agent/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 633, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSession(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Failed to create session.
```

Comment: Tensorboard shouldnt need a gpu.

Tensorboard's main role is to parse events pb files and display them on the web. There is not any heavy computing and the GPU shouldnt be needed?  How are you installing tensorflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorboard 1.7.0 seems to occupy about 150MB on the GPU. See [this open Tensorboard issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1107). Looks like it's in the process of being resolved.

An option in the interim is to limit the percentage of memory Tensorflow is allowed to allocate per process upfront as detailed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). This way you can ensure a certain percentage of memory is reserved for other tasks on the GPU that you might want to run during training.

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.8)

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```