# How to prevent Tensorflow from allocating the totality of a GPU memory when using eager execution?

Tags: tensorflow

I have pretty much the same question that has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory), with a slight difference though:

I'm working on a server with a few GPUs that I share with my colleagues for training our deep learning models. The server should also run a small web application that samples from our models. The sampling script uses the relatively new [eager execution](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager). In theory it allows me to stop Tensorflow from allocating all the GPU memory by providing a configuration like this:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
tf.enable_eager_execution(config=config)
```

In practice this does not work though. The documentation of the eager execution also states that not all the configuration options that work for sessions will work in eager execution ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/enable_eager_execution#args)). But how can I limit the used memory then?

I know that I can limit the visible devices like this:

```
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"
```

But I don't want to constantly block an entire GPU for a task that gets called very occasionally and actually needs way less memory.

Answer (score 1):

Which tensorflow version are you using?
I'm using tensorflow v1.12 built from source (r1.12 branch) on Ubuntu 16.04 with Cuda 9.2 and Cudnn 7.2.1 and the allow_growth option seems to work as expected with eager execution.

Comment: I did some experiments and yes, you are right. It seems to work when I do everything in pure Tensorflow. I use Keras though and thought it would inherit that configuration. Thanks for now. I will post an update when I find a solution to that.