# SageMaker slow when using Multi-GPU with keras.utils.multi_gpu_model

Tags: amazon-web-services, keras, amazon-sagemaker, multi-gpu

Yes am trying to implement a seq2seq model. Can anyone direct me on how to use multi-gpus in keras on AWS SageMaker.

I tried the code on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53488870/sagemaker-fails-when-using-multi-gpu-with-keras-utils-multi-gpu-model/53754450#53754450) it still didnt not work or improve the speed am using the p2.16xlarge instance which comes with 16 GPUs

Comment: can you share the code you've tried?