# How to get cudnn to work ? ( failed to initialize )

Tags: python, keras

Got this error on windows 10

> UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably
>   because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning
>   log message was printed above. [[{{node conv2d_1/convolution}} =
>   Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT,
>   _class=["loc:@training_1/Adam/gradients/conv2d_1/convolution_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter"],
>   data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID",
>   strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](training_1/Adam/gradients/conv2d_1/convolution_grad/Conv2DBackpropFilter-0-TransposeNHWCToNCHW-LayoutOptimizer,
>   conv2d_1/kernel/read)]] [[{{node loss_1/mul/_267}} =
>   _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_782_loss_1/mul",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

I have RTx 2070 and :

Python 3.6.5
tf 1.12.0
tf-gpu 1.12.0
cuda 9.0 with all patches. 
cudnn 7.3.1 
keras 2.2.4

I know nvdia page for cudnn and I read some other answers here. I am interested in small details that are missing. After moving 3 files to 3 directories in the CUDA folder, is there one more step ? Perhaps there is an order in which different parts need to be installed ?

Cuda seems to work fine, python sees it, also matlab sees it.

The error happens while running this code for mnist that I got from the web, which works if I uninstall tensorflow-gpu and use tensorflow on cpu.

An example of great help in the past  was that  you can't install cuda unless you go custom and uncheck the visual studio option. 
Thank you !

Comment: I had exactly the same error on the same configuration. This [simple steps](https://github.com/pplcc/ubuntu-tensorflow-pytorch-setup) worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with an RTX 2070 card using CUDA 10...

The solution was to use:

> config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

in tensor flow.

More info on how to use that parameter:
[How to prevent tensorflow from allocating the totality of a GPU memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory)

Comment: What does that have to do with the question? The question is about libcudnn, you are answering about memory...

Comment: I had the same problem and this hack actually worked for me. Although it sounds like a joke, but it is not.

Answer (score 0):

RTX cards [require CUDA 10](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1042920/which-version-of-cuda-can-work-with-rtx-2080/) I think.