# MXNet - How to Prevent Full Memory Allocation

Tags: mxnet

Is there any way to prevent full GPU memory allocation for MXNet? So that it only allocates what it needs and not the whole GPU memory.

I want to use another model in Tensorflow/Keras on the same GPU alongside MXNet and it seems that the whole memory gets reserved by MXNet.

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MXNet allocates memory [as needed](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/11062). Perhaps there is a memory leak in your program or Tensorflow is trying to pre-allocate the memory on the entire GPU which is the [default behavior](https://riptutorial.com/tensorflow/example/31879/control-the-gpu-memory-allocation). That behavior is configurable with [tf.GPUOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory). See the links on how to use those options.

Hope that helps,
Vishaal