# tensorflow - GPU reaches maximum RAM capacity and get Out Of Memory (OOM)

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, recurrent-neural-network

I run my Bidirectional GRU encoder-decoder with attention using Tesla V100 GPU. My training data are 800 with variative token inside the data. It can be from 771 to 25,672 tokens. When I run it, my memory consumption reaches maximum and then it crashed because of OOM. Then I try to run smaller data (10 data) to the same model, and it run succesfully, but it also consume maximum RAM. I already tried run that 10 data with same code in Tesla K80 12GB (Google Colaboratory) and it only consume about 3GB. I already use `allow_growth` but it doesnt fix the error.

Here are the details of software and hardware I have:

- Tesla V100 PCIE 16GB
- Ubuntu 18.04
- NVIDIA-SMI 418.67
- CUDA 10.0
- CuDNN 7.4.2
- Python 3.6
- Tensorflow 1.13.1
- Keras 2.2.4

Here are hyperparameters of my model:

- embedding size = 100
- hidden unit = 512
- alignment unit = 512
- max_len_summary = 450
- learning rate = 0.01

This is my code of the model

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, None, embedding_size])
    y_label = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1,max_summary_len, embedding_size])
    initial_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(embedding_size,1))

    Wa = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_unit, hidden_unit],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=0.001))
    v_a = tf.transpose(tf.zeros([alignment_unit,1],dtype=tf.float32))
    Ua = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([alignment_unit, 2*hidden_unit],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=0.001))

    Wu = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_unit, embedding_size],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))
    Uu = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_unit, hidden_unit],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))
    Cu = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_unit, 2*hidden_unit],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))

    Wr = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_unit, embedding_size],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))
    Ur = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_unit, hidden_unit],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))
    Cr = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_unit, 2*hidden_unit],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))

    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_unit, embedding_size],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))
    U = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_unit, hidden_unit],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))
    C = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_unit, 2*hidden_unit],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))

    Ww_o = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([embedding_size, embedding_size],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))
    Wc_o = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([embedding_size, 2*hidden_unit],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))
    Ws_o = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([embedding_size, hidden_unit],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))

    Wo = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([embedding_size, 1],seed=seed, mean=mean, stddev=stddev))
    b_o = tf.zeros([embedding_size, 1])

    # define model
    """__encoder___"""
    encoder_LSTM = tf.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU(hidden_unit,return_sequences=True,return_state=True)
    encoder_LSTM_rev=tf.keras.layers.CuDNNGRU(hidden_unit,return_state=True,return_sequences=True,go_backwards=True)

    encoder_outputs, state_h = encoder_LSTM(x)
    encoder_outputsR, state_hR = encoder_LSTM_rev(x)

    state_hfinal=Add()([state_h,state_hR])
    encoder_outputs_final = tf.concat([encoder_outputs,encoder_outputsR], axis=2)

    """__decoder___"""
    initial_state = tf.zeros([hidden_unit,1], dtype=tf.float32)

    arr = tf.reshape(initial_input, (1, embedding_size))
    def decoderStep(arr, last_output,last_state, step):
        prev_state_rep = tf.tile(last_state, (1, tf.shape(encoder_outputs_final)[1])) #something wrong #nilai state diulang sesuai panjang input

        e = tf.matmul(v_a, tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(Wa,prev_state_rep), tf.matmul(Ua, tf.reshape(encoder_outputs_final,[2*hidden_unit,-1])))))

        pembilang = tf.math.exp(e)
        penyebut = tf.reduce_sum(pembilang, axis=1)
        penyebut = tf.reshape(penyebut, [1,1])
        penyebut = tf.tile(penyebut, (1, tf.shape(e)[1])) #nilai penyebut diulang sesuai panjang input
        alphas = pembilang/penyebut

        c = tf.reduce_sum(alphas*tf.reshape(encoder_outputs_final,[2*hidden_unit, -1]),axis=1)
        c = tf.expand_dims(c,1)

        u = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Wu, last_output) + tf.matmul(Uu, last_state) + tf.matmul(Cu, c))
        r = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(Wr, last_output) + tf.matmul(Ur, last_state) + tf.matmul(Cr, c))
        s_ = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(W, last_output) + tf.multiply(tf.matmul(U, r), tf.matmul(U, last_state)) + tf.matmul(C,c))
        s = tf.multiply(1-u, last_state) + tf.multiply(u, s_)

        o = tf.matmul(Ww_o, last_output) + tf.matmul(Wc_o, c) + tf.matmul(Ws_o, s)
        y_pred = tf.multiply(Wo, o) + b_o

        arr = tf.concat([arr,tf.reshape(y_pred, (1, embedding_size))], 0)

        return [arr, y_pred, s, tf.add(step, 1)]

    i = tf.constant(0)
    each_step = lambda c, a, b, step: tf.less(step, max_summary_len-1)
    predss,ltm_pred, lstm_state, _ = tf.while_loop(each_step, decoderStep, [arr, initial_input, initial_state, i] ,shape_invariants=[tf.TensorShape([None, embedding_size]),initial_input.get_shape(),initial_state.get_shape(),i.get_shape()])
    preds=tf.expand_dims(predss,0)

    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_label, preds)
    #   loss=tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_label * tf.log(tf.math.abs(preds)), axis=[0]))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(loss)

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

Here is the error message:

```
ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1024,8370] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node while/mul (defined at ta_skenario1.py:226) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

     [[node mean_squared_error/value (defined at ta_skenario1.py:246) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

This is the result of `nvidia-smi`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A5UO.jpg)

Any help? Thank you

**UPDATE**: I just realize that my code always gets OOM in Tensorflow (decoder) code part. Its never get OOM in Keras CuDNNGRU. Any suggestion to change my code to be simpler? Thanks

**UPDATE**: I changed my embedding size to 64, hidden unit to 128, alignment unit 64. The OOM error is gone, but it takes very long time (approx. 13 mins) for 1 epoch

Comment: I had a problem like this. try installing an older version of tensorflow.

Comment: When you say you have used `allow_growth`, does that mean you have tried setting it to `False`? If `allow_growth` is `True`, it allows TensorFlow to use the entire GPU's memory.

Comment: @DaduKhan I tried to downgrade my tensorflow to 1.11 but it doesnt compatible with my CUDA version

Comment: @LukeDeLuccia I changed the `allow_growth` option to `False` and the problem still persists.

Comment: How are you setting `allow_growth`? I was wrong, `allow_growth` must be `True` like you originally mentioned. Are doing it similarly to the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory#answer-37454574? You can also limit the amount of memory with `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction`.

Comment: @LukeDeLuccia I set it to `True`. I also add that parameter with value 0.866 but it doesnt takes any effect :/

Comment: I think your while loop has a problem. In `each_step = lambda c, a, b, step: tf.less(step, max_summary_len-1)` where is the value of `step` coming from?

Comment: @dgumo it is coming from this `def decoderStep(arr, last_output,last_state, step):`