# Computer freezes and crashes when training tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I had a ton of errors, but once I got it to start training it just crashed my computer. I watched in the task manager as CPU and memory went up. I switched to tensorflow-GPU as well, which didn't solve the issue. I have an i7-6700k and a gtx 1070, with 16gb ram.

Comment: You can set the percentage of memory Tensorflow can use following the answers in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory

Comment: There's nothing much we can do to help if you don't provide the code. To take a shot in the dark what I can suggest is that your CUDA is not setup correctly and tensorflow-gpu is not actually using GPU.

Comment: I will try to limit the memory, if that fails I'll reinstall CUDA.Q