# No additional memory from Colab Pro+

Tags: google-colaboratory

I've been running [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QBsaDAZv8np29FPbvjffbE1eytoJcsgA#scrollTo=X5gODNAMEUCR) with the Runtime Type as "high-RAM" "GPU." I was getting the following error:

> CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 64.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.90 GiB total capacity; 14.81 GiB already allocated; 31.75 MiB free; 14.94 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

So I upgraded from Pro to Pro+, because that's supposed to give me more memory, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: The additional RAM refers to machine RAM, rather than GPU memory.

Comment: Do you use TF? If so, try to set allow_grow flag to True, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37454574/8788960).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think a better GPU was promised with Colab Pro+.

[image]

Comment: Dang, you're certainly right. I didn't understand the difference between the RAM and the GPU's memory, I just thought increasing my RAM would fix my memory errors. Thank you.

Comment: This puzzles me because their pitch for becoming a paid Colab Pro user includes "more memory" than free users. I get the same out of memory error whether I'm free or Pro.

Comment: @cbmtrx are y on pro or pro plus?

Comment: @KevinK I went from free to Pro this am; haven't been able to run a single program since I paid.

Comment: @cbmtrx that is all. Did u check ur colab settings upon initialization?

Comment: @KevinK I'm using a public Colab that I had been successfully using all of yesterday as a free. Suddenly today I can't use it without it failing. Doesn't seem like I would need to change how I was using it.