# Tensorflow 2.5 limit GPU memory usage

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a pipeline program that runs three inference processes in one go. However, the third process will hit error below.

```
RuntimeError: Error in virtual void* 
faiss::gpu::StandardGpuResourcesImpl::allocMemory(const 
faiss::gpu::AllocRequest&) at /__w/faiss-wheels/faiss-
wheels/faiss/faiss/gpu/StandardGpuResources.cpp:452: Error: 'err == 
cudaSuccess' failed: StandardGpuResources: alloc fail type 
TemporaryMemoryBuffer dev 0 space Device stream 0x1e9eb170 size 
1073741824 bytes (cudaMalloc error out of memory [2])
```

I am using a RTX 3070 with 8GB of VRAM. For more detail, the first two processes are inference with pretrained model and third process is a similarity search using [FAISS](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss). I hit error when I tried to move my search index from CPU to GPU in third process. I need to run the search on GPU as my index size is in the scale of million.

Understand that Tensorflow will allocate the entire GPU memory during a process call. I tried the approach of using `set_memory_growth` at the beginning of program but it still does not work.

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
  try:
    for gpu in gpus:
      tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
  except RuntimeError as e:
    print(e)
```

There are answers that suggested using [per_process_gpu_memory_fraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory) but this is no longer available in TF 2.5.

I tracked the memory usage using `tf.config.experimental.get_memory_info('GPU:0')` and below is the log.

```
Beginning of the program - {'current': 0, 'peak': 0}

After first inference - {'current': 281843712, 'peak': 2803776768}

After second inference - {'current': 281844480, 'peak': 2803776768}
```

As the first two inference processes are not using the full memory, is there anyway I can free up the allocated memory for my third process? Or prevent TF 2.5 from allocating the entire memory.

Answer (score 0):

Batch size has a major impact on the amount of GPU memory required for any particular model. You can try reducing your batch size to see if that helps.