# Using ImageDataGenerator and 2 frames as input to VGG16

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras

I am building a VGG image pipeline, and I am trying to input 2 consecutive frames from a video as follows:

```
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
    datagen.fit(X_train)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(224, 224, 6), filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    model.add(Dense(units=4096, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(units=4096, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))

    # opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    opt = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.3)
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(config.CLASH_PATH() + '/models/step_01.h5', monitor='binary_accuracy', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                                 save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
    early = EarlyStopping(monitor='binary_accuracy', min_delta=0, patience=40, verbose=1, mode='auto')

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['binary_accuracy'])
    model.summary()

    model.fit(datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32,
         subset='training', ignore_class_split=True), validation_data=datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=16,
         subset='validation', ignore_class_split=True), steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) / 48,
         epochs=1000, verbose=1,
         callbacks=[checkpoint, early])
```

As you'll note in the 4th line of code, I am passing 224x224x6 which represents two stacked image frames of 224x224x3.  This is necessary since I am using the ImageDataGenerator to pass my data.

Unfortunately I am getting the following error message:

```
NumpyArrayIterator is set to use the data format convention "channels_last" (channels on axis 3), i.e. expected either 1, 3, or 4 channels on axis 3. However, it was passed an array with shape (6666, 224, 224, 6) (6 channels).
```

From other reading on stackoverflow, I have seen that I can stack my frames using layers.concatenate, but how would I then modify my generator to keep the flow of frames in sync?

Comment: Why not simply use `X_train` and `y_train` (with a manual split for train/valid) as inputs to the `model.fit()` (wo using the generator)? Doesn't look like you're doing any data augmentation. Also [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow) specifically says it accepts x upto a rank of 4.

Comment: I introduced the generator since the full dataset was triggering a GPU memory error. Utilizing smaller, generator produced batch sizes has eliminated the memory error.

Comment: That sounds pretty weird. It shouldn't happen (from my exp). Have you tried setting `allow_memory_growth`?

Comment: `Conv2D` is designed for images, or what can be represented by images. We can't (practically) have a six channel input shape image with current, popular image tools. You need one, three, or four channels. Why not just pass two color images? [You can limit memory growth to prevent oom error.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34199233/how-to-prevent-tensorflow-from-allocating-the-totality-of-a-gpu-memory)

Comment: I will utilize the memory growth approach and eliminate the generator.  Thanks